# Multiple Accounts suddenly added in Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I'm currently developing an app which is only accessible by me for now. I can already connect to Firebase but somehow I noticed that there's alot of unknown email added. I'm expecting it to have around 4 email which I have used for testing. May I know why this happened? And will this affect my app if ever I finished developing it?

Note that I didn't share/upload any info/keys that I'm using.
I was thinking that someone might have used my info/keys mistakenly that is why this happens.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It seems to be similar to https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/235171/my-firebase-project-has-unknown-users-has-my-google-cloud-service-account-been

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I saw that one of the emails I got is the same as what you have shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you uploaded your App to the Play Store such accounts are created by Google while they verify your app. That is normal. You don't need to worry about it.

Also see: [My Firebase project has unknown users, has my google cloud service account been compromised?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/235171/my-firebase-project-has-unknown-users-has-my-google-cloud-service-account-been)

Comment: I just worry that somehow my database was compromised. Thanks for clarifying.